# Force method from base to call a subclass new method

Tags: c#, class, methods, public, protected

My understanding is that a subclass behaves exactly like the parent class except for the additional methods or those that get "rewritten" with the `new` and `override` keywords. Apparently, that's not correct.

Please see the code below (brackets removed for readability)

```
class BIG
    protected void Output(string text = "")
        Console.WriteLine("BIG - " + text);

    public void CallingOutput()
        Output("Outputting...");

class SMALL:BIG
    public new void Output(string text = "")
        Console.WriteLine("SMALL - " + text);

class Program
    static void Main(string[] args)
        SMALL foo = new SMALL();
```

I already know that I can hide the `BIG.Output(string)` in SMALL with the `new` keyword. When calling directly, it works perfectly.

```
>> foo.Output("Outputting...")
SMALL - Outputting...
```

Here is where it conflicts with my understanding. I thought defining `class SMALL:BIG` was exactly the same as if I define `class SMALL` and copy-paste all method from BIG. In short, I thought the SMALL class above was equivalent to this:

```
class SMALL
    public void Output(string text = "")
        Console.WriteLine("SMALL - " + text);

    public void CallingOutput()
        Output("Outputting...");
```

Apparently that is not correct because

```
>> foo.CallingOutput()
BIG - Outputting...
```

It is still using the original `Output(string)` from `BIG` when called indirectly.

What is the right way of doing it so that `foo.CallingOutput()` would output

`"SMALL - Outputting..."`

Assuming that I don't have access to `BIG` and not allowed to make any changes. And I don't want to have to hide `CallingOutput()` also because that is basically rewriting the class.
(Yes, hiding `CallingOutput()` makes it work)

I did some searching before posting this and found a similar question in `C++`. However, the answer for that is not possible.

1. I don't believe that. Such a powerful language and yet, there's no way of telling the compiler which method is which.
2. It's a different language so this post is allowed as it can't be considered a duplication.

Comment: Declare the method `virtual` in base class and `override` in child then base will case it, `new` doesn't work that way by design

Comment: Yeah, `override` and `new` are not interchangeable. They have different effects. Your question could be made clearer by showing your use of `foo`; both `foo`'s type and the object creation.

Comment: @abatishchev As stated, I'm not allowed to make changes to BIG.

Comment: Then don't inherit from it. It was not designed for inheritance. You could, instead, use composition. Create your SMALL class to take a reference to a BIG object and use it as needed. Won't work for all cases, but might get you where you need to go?

Comment: Then it's by design: you try to hack BIG (change its behavior by overriding what isn't virtual) and the framework doesn't allow you to do that (new works only in the scope of the same type) because that's not how BIG was designed and intended to behave, sorry. However see the answer by @itsme86 - this is the correct way (but not always applicable)

Comment: "hack", that explains it. Thanks @abatishchev! @itsme86 can you rewrite that as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replace keywords `new` by `override` as this :

```
class SMALL:BIG
public override void Output(string text = "")
    Console.WriteLine("SMALL - " + text);
```

Comment: I can't make changes to `BIG` and `BIG.Output()` is not marked virtual, abstract, or override, so I can't do this.

Comment: do it in your base class

Comment: What do you mean by base class? Isn't BIG the base class?

Comment: yes! read this article you will understand   [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override)

Comment: I don't understand. I stated twice, in the question and in the comment that I'm not allowed to make changes to the base class. It is as it is, and it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override so I can't use the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a shim

You can't modify or override anything in the existing class unless it was designed to be overridden. This is by design.

That being said, you can create a new "shim" (pass-through) class that is exactly like the original class but with the member being declared as virtual. This is accomplished by using both `new` and `virtual` modifiers.

Once you have the shim class, you can override the method per normal. Example:

```
class Big
{
    public void Output(string text) { Console.WriteLine("Big - {0}", text); }

    public void CallingOutput()
    {
        Output("Outputting...");
    }
}

class Shim : Big
{
    public new virtual void Output(string text) { base.Output(text); }

    public void CallingOutput()
    {
        Output("Outputting...");
    }
}
```

Now you have a Shim class that will allow what you want. So subclass it (instead of Big) and see what happens:

```
class Small : Shim
{
    public override void Output(string text) { Console.WriteLine("Small - {0}", text); }
}
```

Test it:

```
Shim s = new Shim();
s.CallingOutput();   //Original behavior

Shim s = new Small();
s.CallingOutput();   //Overridden behavior
```

Output:

```
Big - Outputting...
Small - Outputting...
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AMsDYZ)

Comment: No, that is not what I want. The goal was to get `CallingOutput` to call the `Output` in `SMALL`. I already achieved what you had in your example in my question, and without even using the `Shim` class. Please check it again!

Comment: As I said, you can't have what you want, by design. In my example you can use `Shim` instead of big. It is different from what you've already done, as the override in Small actually works. I'll update the example code.

Comment: Well, also as stated in my question, I don't want to "rewrite" `CallingOutput` because that is basically rewriting `BIG`. And yes, you're correct, it shouldn't be overridden if it wasn't designed to be so in the first place.

Comment: I understand. Sorry, you can't have exactly what you want. I would suggest a shim is less work than rewriting BIG, since you'd still have access to `this`, still be able to access protected members, still be able to store an instance in an `IEnumerable<BIG>` or pass it as a parameter where a `BIG` was expected, etc. Your call though.