# Call subclass `new` method from parent

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, subclass

I have a base and sub class such as:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        MethodB();
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        Debug.Log("BaseClass MethodB");
    }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public new void MethodB() // <- without `new` keyword there's a warning on this line
    {
        Debug.Log("SubClass MethodB");
        base.MethodB();
    }
}
```

When the `MethodA` of the BaseClass instance is called it calls `MethodB` but only of the BaseClass, and not of the SubClass first.  e.g.

```
var subclass = new SubClass();
subclass.MethodA(); // Does not log "SubClass MethodB" first.  Only logs "BaseClass MethodB"
```

How do you make sure the parent methods call the subclass methods?

Note, without the `new` keyword on the `MethodB` line, Visual Studio gives a warning: `'SubClass.MethodB()' hides inherited member 'BaseClass.MethodB()'.  Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`

Comment: Note a similar question is asked here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50184616/539490). But it's different because that question is about when you can not modify the base class.  I hope this question and answer are significantly different / more concise.  If you disagree then please vote to close.

Comment: Pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717570/why-does-calling-a-method-in-my-derived-class-call-the-base-class-method. Actually there are hundreds of similar ones. This question is asked slightly differently once a week I guess.

Comment: Yes @PavelAnikhouski that's the kind of answer I was looking for.  Thanks!  Shall we vote to close?

Comment: @AJP you can vote to close or delete this question

Comment: I can't delete it, it won't let me.  Have voted to close instead.  Thanks.

Comment: @AJP You can delete the question if you delete the answer first. (Both is entirely up to you.)

Answer (score 1):

To get Subclass.MethodB to be called from your base class you need to use the `virtual` and `override` keywords.  For example:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public void MethodA() // invoking this will correctly log "SubClass MethodB" followed by "BaseClass MethodB"
    {
        MethodB();
    }

    public virtual void MethodB()
    {
        Debug.Log("BaseClass MethodB");
    }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void MethodB()
    {
        Debug.Log("SubClass MethodB");
        base.MethodB();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you answered your own question?

Comment: Yeah, seems fishy!

Comment: It's perfectly allowed to post questions and answering them yourself for the sake of documenting... though in this case it's really _really_ basic c# language functionality, so I'm not sure if it's useful at all. "How to override" is like, the first lesson in subclassing in c#.

Comment: @Nyerguds yes, but why ask a question then answer it within the same minute?

Comment: As I said. "for the sake of documenting". This is posted here not because OP had a problem and found the solution, but specifically to put a solution to this problem on SO. And yes, that's allowed.

Comment: @Nyerguds ok fair enough, but this is clearly an attempt to gain XP.

Comment: So? You don't _get_ xp for answering your own question. And if it helps other people out and they upvote it, then that XP is deserved. Again, according to the rules, this is a legitimate way of getting XP. Also, I don't think someone with 17k XP will really bother doing things as "an attempt to gain XP".

Comment: @Nyerguds yes, I see your point, but as you noted earlier, this is very basic stuff, so it just seemed strange.

Comment: @Nyerguds I'm new to StackOverflow but isn't there a way to create a question for the sake of documentation where you answer it directly, instead of creating a "normal" question ? Which would have made this post more legitimate.

Comment: @PhilippeB. that's what I tried to do.  I'd never seen it before but there's a little check box saying "Answer your own question" ... which an hour earlier I couldn't click but after experimenting and finding the (to this very basic C# answer) I could then answer my own question :)

Comment: @Jonathan Barclay unfortunately it costed me an hour in frustration and searching for "c# call subclass method from parent" didn't give anything useful.  I thought this would be a useful answer to someone but appears not.  Please vote to close.  I can't delete this now as too many comments.

Comment: @Nyerguds yeah I should do those beginner lessons.  I haven't.  The `new` word led me off down the wrong path.  It was surprising that Visual Studio only gave one rather than two valid suggestions (the other missing suggestion being `virtual / override`).